# Direct and Indirect objects in "I take my kids to school"

Tags: objects, direct-objects

In the sentence

> I take my kids to school.

I would be the subject and the verb would be **take**.

Now, as the verb **take** is acted upon the kids, I thought my kids was the direct object and *the school* would be the indirect object.

However, my professor said that the school is actually a direct object.

I'm wondering, do I have both the kids and the school as two separate direct objects?

Comment: Your professor appears not to know what a direct object is. _School_ is the object of the preposition _to_, but the term ‘direct object’ is not usually applied to prepositional objects.

Comment: ... and the PP "to school" is a complement of "take".

Answer (score 1):

**Indirect object** is when you can say it without the preposition "to".

> I gave the book to him.

has direct object "the book" but no indirect object.

> I gave him the book.

has direct object "the book" and indirect object "him".

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence

'I take my kids to school'

***my kids*** is the direct object as ***to take*** is a transitive verb.

The phrase 
***to school*** is the adverbial modifier.

Comment: I think it would be better to say that the PP "to school" is a goal complement, not a modifier, since it has to be licensed by a verb of motion, in this case "take".

Answer (score 0):

user307254 is correct.

To further elaborate,

Indirect objects show **whom** the action is for.

Example:

I buy my mum a present.

**a present** = direct object

**my mum** = indirect object

However, if you say "I buy a present for my mum."

**a present** = direct object

But now **my mum** is part of a prepositional phrase (or adverbial modifier) beginning with the preposition "for".

In your example, "**to school**" is a prepositional phrase with school being the object of a preposition.